# node warnings: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: displayErrorFunction is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

We have two variants of code that both return the same node warnings.

> variant 1

```
import axios from 'axios';

const correctEndpoint = `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/dbconnections/signup`;
const headers = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
};

const registerWithAuth0 = async (payload, redirectFunction, displayErrorFunction) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(correctEndpoint, payload, headers);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      redirectFunction();
    } else {
      displayErrorFunction();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    displayErrorFunction();
  } 
}

export default registerWithAuth0;
```

> variant 2

```
import axios from 'axios';

const correctEndpoint = `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/dbconnections/signup`;
const headers = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
};

const registerWithAuth0 = (payload, redirectFunction, displayErrorFunction) => {
  axios.post(correctEndpoint, payload, headers)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        redirectFunction();
      } else {
        displayErrorFunction();
      }
    })
    .catch (() => {
      displayErrorFunction();
    });
}

export default registerWithAuth0;
```

all jest tests pass, but we can see some of the following **node warnings**:

```
(node:26886) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: displayErrorFunction is not a function
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:26886) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:26886) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:26886) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: displayErrorFunction is not a function
(node:26886) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

we are using:

- node v14.17.1
- react v17.0.1
- jest v26.6.3
- babel-jest v26.6.3
- @babel/core v7.14.0

**Any ideas about what might be the issue here?**

There are some similar issues being reported online, but not quite the same:

- [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940043/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-this-error-originated-either-by-throwing-insid)
- [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: createUser is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64594863/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-typeerror-createuser-is-not-a-function)

Comment: are u passing the `displayErrorFunction` parameter in your test cases? if not then make a default argument of `displayErrorFunction = ()=>{}`

Comment: Thanks, @AritraChakraborty that solved it, there was a test case that did not have it.

Comment: Okay i will add this as an answer so that others can find it. feel free to accept it @dankilev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that any of the test cases is missing that parameter or not.

Alternative you can add a default value for `displayErrorFunction`.

```
(payload, redirectFunction, displayErrorFunction = ()=>{} ) => {

}
```

Comment: In our case, we needed to amend the tests as the function is mandatory, however, if it was optional this is a brilliant solution. You pointed us in the right direction to check if the function was actually being passed as a parameter for the tests.